# Converting result of MySQL query in Django to JSON

Tags: django, json

So I query my database using a mySQL query like so:

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select winner,count(winner) as count from DB")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Now I want to send the table in data to my app (as a GET request) in JSON. Doing this is not sending a properly formatted JSON response and I am unable to parse it on the client side.

```
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json;charset=utf8')
```

The json.dumps(data) returns this:

```
    [["John Doe", 45]]
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.core import serializers

json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)
return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

However not everything can be serialized like this into JSON, some things need a custom [encoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2)

You should use a model and the ORM instead of writing your own SQL.
You could easily convert your statement to this simple model and succinctly ORM call.

```
class Winner(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
```

and your database call would now be `Winner.objects.all()` which would give all winners

and with the count

```
Winner.objects.annotate(wins=Count('name'))
```

Comment: I tried this. But I'm getting this error:
        
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'`

But I will go through the Django docs, thank you.

Comment: Exactly, you get a tuple back and the `serialize` method could give you trouble. What you ultimately want to do, IMO, is to change from writing your own SQLs and transition into Djangos ORM since you want fields relating to your SQL resultset. What you're after is a json that looks like this `{'name': 'John Doe', 'wins':45}`.

Comment: Ah, I shied away from Django ORM's for some reason. But I see in this case that would make the most sense. Thank you, I am going to try this!

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is properly formatted, but you are dumping a list, you should dump a dictionary instead... something like:

```
myData = {'people': data}

json.dumps(myData)
```

The point is this: a valid json response must start and end with curly braces, so in order to serve a valid json you have to dump a Python dictionary object as a "root object"... in other words you need at least an object with a key.

From http://json.org

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> ```
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
> ```
>
> list, or associative array.
>       An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: That does work! But is there any way to use the names of the Fields they belong to directly? This seems a bit redundant. For every key-value pair, I would have to type in the name of the key?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db import connections
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def testRawQuery(request):
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("select winner,count(winner) as count from DB")
    objs = cursor.fetchall() 
    json_data = []
    for obj in objs:
        json_data.append({"winner" : obj[0], "count" : obj[1]})
    return JsonResponse(json_data, safe=False)
```